# How can I write this query in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query

```
SELECT t.NomeTipo, sum(v.QtdProduto) 
FROM [dbo].[Vendas] AS V 
RIGHT JOIN [dbo].[Produtos] AS P ON V.IdProduto = P.IdProduto
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tipos] AS T ON P.IdTipo = T.IdTipo  
group by t.NomeTipo 
order by t.NomeTipo
```

I have tried this

```
var queryTipos = from vendas in repositorioVendas.Vendas
join produtos in repositorioProduto.Produtos.DefaultIfEmpty()
on vendas.IdProduto equals produtos.IdProduto
join tipos in repositorioTipo.Tipos
on produtos.IdTipo equals tipos.IdTipo
group vendas by new { tipos.NomeTipo, vendas.QtdProduto }
into novoGrupo
select new
{
    NomeTipo = novoGrupo.Key.NomeTipo,
    QtdProduto = novoGrupo.Sum(x => x.QtdProduto)
};
```

With this query I got only two results, but when I run straight from the database I get something like this:

```
Bebidas     16
Bolos       14
Frios       16
Pães        21
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I do, but it didn't not work so far

Comment: Then [edit] your question to show what you have so far. We are not a code writing service, but we will help you fix things that don't work.

Comment: sorry I am new here =[

Comment: Rewrite your SQL to use a left join, then google "left join linq".

Comment: Could you post your entitles and tables structures?

Comment: In my database the "left" or "right" join give me the same result.

Comment: One issue is that in the SQL you group by NomeTipo, but in the Linq you're grouping by NomeTipo and QtdProduto.

Comment: What I need is to group the field "NomeTipo" from table types and sum the "QtdProduto" values of the product sold related to that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to realize that you can rewrite your query with a left join instead of a right join by swapping the order of the first two tables and that Linq doesn't have a way to really handle right joins.  Also you're grouping was wrong.

```
var queryTipos = from produtos in repositorioProduto.Produtos 
                 join vendas_pj in repositorioVendas.Vendas
                 on vendas_pj.IdProduto equals produtos.IdProduto into joined
                 from vendas in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join tipos in repositorioTipo.Tipos
                 on produtos.IdTipo equals tipos.IdTipo
                 group vendas by tipos.NomeTipo
                 into novoGrupo
                 select new
                 {
                    NomeTipo = novoGrupo.Key,
                    QtdProduto = novoGrupo.Sum(x => x.QtdProduto)
                 };
```

Basically a Left join in SQL

```
From TableA
Left Join TableB 
On TableA.ID = TableB.ID
```

is done in Linq like this

```
from a in repo.TableA
join b_pj in repo.TableB
on a.ID equals b_pj.ID into joined
from b in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
```